# Не подключается к ядру в jupyter-notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv

Решил начать работать с jupyter-notebook, но столкнулся с такой проблемой. После написания в консоль jupyter-notebook, открывается localhost:8888/tree, там я создаю python3 файл, но в строке состояния подключения показывается "no connection to kernel". Естественно при написании любой строчки кода, появляется IN[*] и нет никакого вывода, пробовал искать в гугле, но толком ответа не нашел, везде пишут остановите/перезапустите ядро, но это не помогает. Кто то пишет выключите антивирус, но у меня его нет. Делаю все в виртуальном окружении через virtualenv --no-site-packages (вдруг это что-то меняет)
Причем, пользовался jupyterом раньше, с этого же ноутбука, и все работало. 
Возможно это из-за того, что я подключен к интернету через мобильную точку доступа?
У кого нибудь была такая же проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У кого возникнет та же проблема - вот вам возможное решение
При установке jupyter через pip, вместе с юпитером устанавливается куча пакетов, среди которых tornado. Так вот торнадо версии выше 4.5.3 почему то некорректно отрабатывает соединение через веб сокет. Решение - понизить торнадо до 4.5.3
У меня выглядело следующим образом

```
pip list
pip uninstall tornado
pip install tornado==4.5.3
```

И сразу соединение установилось